# How do I print the user and umask for all running processes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

The username is in column one and PID in column two of `ps gaux`, so I have:

```
ps gaux | awk '{print $2;}' | while read line ; do grep -i umask /proc/$line/status ; done
```

but is there a way to print the username as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps

```bash
ps gaux | awk '{printf $1 " " ; system("grep Umask /proc/"$2"/status | tr -dc [:digit:]"); printf "\n"}'
```

Explanation:

1. get output from ps
2. print first column (username) and space
3. run the grep and remove everything except the actual umask, which is a number (awk does not print the command output, it gets just printed directly from the subshells stdout)
4. print a new line

Comment: I think the status of the system command is printed (i.e. `0`) instead of the output of the grep command...?

Comment: Yeah, i just noticed that too, sorry for that, give me a sec

Comment: @thebjorn fixed it. sorry :S